# How do you hide a form until a button is clicked in HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, button, hide

I want to hide an html form within a button. I tried adding a button around the form similar to a parent div with a child div, but that didn't seem to work. I'm confused about how to add the "hide" element. Do I have to use javascript or jQuery? Or is there a simple way to do it with just CSS or HTML?

Thanks in advance!!

```css
/*LOGIN*/

html {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.loginform ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.loginform il {
  display: inline;
  float: top right;
}

label {
  display: block;
  color: #ED4337;
}

label:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.cf:before .cf:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  *zoom: 1;
}

 :focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.loginform input:not([type=submit]) {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
}

.loginform input[type=submit] {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #64c8ef;
  /*old browsers*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #64c8ef 0%, #00a2e2 100%);
  /*FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(100%, #00a2e2));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #64c8ef 0%, #00a2e2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #64c8ef 0%, #00a2e2 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #64c8ef 0%, #00a2e2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #64c8ef 0%, #00a2e2);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient ( startColors)='#64c8ef', endColorstr='#00a2e2', GradientType=0);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
}


/*END LOG IN */
```

```html
<!--LOG IN INFO-->
<button class="log">Log In
         <section class="loginfrom cf">
          <form name="login" action="index_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <ul>
              <li><label for="username">Email</label>
              <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com"
              required></li>

              <li><label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="email" name="password" placeholder="password" required></li>
              <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Login"></li>
            </ul>
          </form>
        </section>
      </button>
<!--END LOG IN INFO-->
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to get out of that large button? Do you want to hide the form until someone clicks the "unhide" button?

Comment: @CharlesShiller: Yes! Exactly. I'm just unsure how to hide the form until the actual clicking happens.

Comment: @CharlesShiller: I have a BUNCH of stuff in my CSS-- I edited it because the snippet didn't add it all in the first time. Where would I add the display: hide; ? :P thanks so much for your help; i'm self taught so I'm just trying to get the most out of all the resources I can :) PS: the .log  in the CSS is the login button, but I have a separate .log:hover as well.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Sorry, it's display: none or visibility: hidden.

Comment: @Cheyenne, when you say you want to hide a form in a button, do you, by any chance, mean you want the form to show when the button is clicked? In this case, you're looking for [modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

Comment: @Andrei yup! That's what I mean. I was trying to follow [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_login_form.asp) tutorial on login screens, and used the first one. something went wrong along the way, and I had to make a specific button for the log in so it didn't get messed with the other buttons I already had on the page; I'm not quite sure what I'm doing. I appreciate all the help, though. I'm going to retry the tutorial and see what happens, now that I know that buttons can't be used to hide things.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, close the button tag `<button class="log">Log in</button>`. Then, hide the form by using css, like `.loginform { display: none; }`

Finally, to show the form when the user clicks the button, you can use jQuery.

```
$('.log').click(function() {
    $('.loginform').css('display', 'block');
});
```

To further understand CSS and Javascript and how they work together, I strongly advise you to read some tutorials and check some examples in W3Schools

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: do i need to insert jQuery somehow, or does the $ do it? I've never used jQuery before.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library and has to be included in your page, in order to use it.  Please check https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp to understand how